# Mysql Where like or like

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

Having an issue with a MySql query. I am looking for a pattern match in three fields and I have tried using brackets to separate each like pattern. Instead of returning the correct number of rows, it returns the all the rows as a result.

Here is the query

```
mysql_query("select * from contacts where contact_name like '%$contact_name%' or bus_name like '%$busname%' or contact_email like '%$contact_email%'");
```

If i search for contact_name like Kim or busname like someword and contact_email like anyword it should only return 1 result.

I think the issue is when a user leaves a search field blank MySql does not like to search for nothing in a like statement. Would i be better catching the field before the search and replace it with an obscure character so it is not empty, or is there a way in the statement that we can deal with a blank search string

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: could you show what the data in your table is like, and an actual example with real values?

Comment: **SQL injection risk ahead!** Please read about prepared statements.

Comment: Hi. Not sure what you mean there. The data in the table holds a persons name in column 1 their business name in column 2 and their email address in column 3 :)

Comment: what do you get if you echo the query string? Are you sure those 3 variables are populated? Using `OR` will match any of the given requirements so if one is blank and there are records that are blank then it matches

Comment: contact_name    bus_name                contact_email

Graham         Belper Party Cakes belperpartycakes@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: 22 records with all the fields populated no empty rows each record has a persons name a business name and an email address

Comment: select * from mail_list where contact_name like '%Kim%' or bus_name like '%%' or contact_email like '%noemail%'

Answer (score 4):

Your instinct is correct that blanks will cause your statement to return all rows.

If the person submits a blank form, the SQL that is run is really:

```
select * from contacts where contact_name like '%%' or bus_name like '%%' or contact_email like '%%'"
```

So obviously, that will return all rows.

**Solution: You need to check first to see that any one of your variables has value, and if you don't have at least one variable with a non-blank/valid value, you should return an error.**

AND I STRONGLY ECHO the posters who said that there are serious SQL injection risks without sanitizing your code!!!

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider your query:

```sql
select * 
from contacts 
where 
    contact_name like '%contact_name%'      -- Condition 1
    or bus_name like '%bus_name%'           -- Condition 2
    or contact_email like '%contact_email%' -- Condition 3
```

Let's see how this is evaluated for any row:

```
 c1 | c2 | c3 | row_returned
----+----+----+--------------
  T |  T |  T |   Yes
  T |  T |  F |   Yes
  T |  F |  T |   Yes
  T |  F |  F |   Yes
  F |  T |  T |   Yes
  F |  T |  F |   Yes
  F |  F |  T |   Yes
  F |  F |  F |   No
```

Consider now what would happen if you use `and` instead of `or`:

```
 c1 | c2 | c3 | row_returned
----+----+----+--------------
  T |  T |  T |   Yes
  T |  T |  F |   No
  T |  F |  T |   No
  T |  F |  F |   No
  F |  T |  T |   No
  F |  T |  F |   No
  F |  F |  T |   No
  F |  F |  F |   No
```

It seems to me that you need to use `and` instead of `or`.

---

As for my comment about SQL injection, I mean that the way your query is written there is an open door for some rogue code to be inserted and damage your data. Imagine that the variable `contact_name` is assigned to something like this:

```
 contact_name = "'; drop table contacts; --"
```

That would be bad.

Please check [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (and also [this](http://xkcd.com/327/) if you want to laugh a bit about what SQL injection can do).

Comment: I am allowing the user to search for a match in any of the three fields where the search is like in case it is misspell. so if there is a match in any of the fields it will produce the result. If i use and then it has to be a match in all 3 fields. I think maybe my issue is if in the submitted fields, if a field is left empty MySql does not like this. So i think i need to change the question a bit. I will edit the initial question :)

Comment: Then you should make some clever code to check for each condition individually, or use `UNION` in your SQL query.

Comment: your answer really helped, thank you so much